# How to handle Finite-state-machine with correlated inputs?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, estimation, dynamic-programming

My system can be represented by the following state-diagram.

[image]

where each arch represents Input/Output when a transition is made from one state to the other.

The inputs to this FSM are correlated. This implies that I can no longer make "independent input" assumption.

My question is: How will this impact on how we use the MARKOV-CHAIN/MARKOV-PROCESS properties in implementing Viterbi algorithm for computing Maximum Likelihood Sequence estimation. Also if someone can comment on the application of BCJR algorithm for MAP estimation of inputs.

Comment: What do the labels on the arcs in the diagram denote?

Comment: It is input/output. I have edited my post to include this information

Comment: Ah...Mealy machines. It has been 5 years since I last studied this topic. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: any text that you might recommend for this topic?